# I cannot open Android Studio after installing it(Mac M1 Sonoma 14.3)

Tags: android

I am using a MacBook Pro M1 with macOS version Sonoma 14.3. I downloaded the latest version of Android Studio from the official website, but after a successful installation, it crashes unexpectedly when I try to open it. Has anyone encountered a similar issue? I appreciate your help greatly.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the application, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully resolved this issue. I checked the error logs in macOS /content and found that the reason was a script I had previously installed to extend the trial period of IntelliJ IDEA. After uninstalling it, I was able to open Android Studio successfully.